# why does anime.js not work on span elements

Tags: anime.js

I'm trying to animate each letter in a header using anime.js, by placing each letter of the header into a span. But for some reason, I can't animate the spans. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Header anime animation</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1 id="mainheader">
                <span class="header-text" id="f">f</span><span class="header-text" id="o-1">o</span><span class="header-text" id="o-2">o</span>
            </h1>
        </header>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/animejs@3.2.1/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
div#wrapper {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

h1#mainheader {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
```

script.js

```js
anime({
    targets: '.header-text',
    translateY: -50,
    duration: 1000,
    delay: anime.stagger(100),
    easing: "easeInOutExpo",
    autoplay: true
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because span elements are inline elements, but anime.js works only on `display: block` or `display: inline-block`. So in style.css, just add

```
span.header-text {
    display: inline-block
}
```